# Why $\nabla \cdot(\vec \varphi \otimes \vec u)$ instead of $\nabla \cdot(\vec u \otimes \vec \varphi)$ in the continuity equation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

From the [Wikipedia entry on the derivation of the Navier-Stokes equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations), the continuity equations for scalar quantities has the following form：
$$
\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\varphi \vec u) + \vec s = \vec 0\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Since
$$
\nabla \cdot (\vec a \otimes \vec b) = (\nabla \cdot \vec a) \vec b + \vec a \cdot \nabla \vec b\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\nabla \cdot (s \vec v) = \nabla s \cdot \vec v + s \nabla \cdot \vec v \label{3}\tag{3}
$$
I get
$$
\nabla \cdot ( \vec a \otimes \vec b) = (\nabla \cdot (\vec a b_x), \nabla \cdot (\vec a b_y))\label{4}\tag{4}
$$
When $\varphi$ is a vector, its components respectively satisfy \eqref{1}, that is,
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial \varphi_x}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\varphi_x \vec u) + s_x = 0 \\
\dfrac{\partial \varphi_y}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\varphi_y \vec u) + s_y = 0
\end{cases}\label{5}\tag{5}
$$

According to \eqref{4}, the two equations \eqref{5} above could be written as the single one below:
$$
\frac{\partial \vec \varphi}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\vec u \otimes \vec \varphi) + \vec s = \vec 0
$$
But in the Wikipedia entry, $\vec \varphi$ is at the left to $\vec u$, i.e.
$$
 \frac{\partial \vec \varphi}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot(\vec \varphi \otimes \vec u) + \vec s = \vec 0
$$
This implies that after substituting $\vec \varphi$ by $\rho \vec u$, my version of the equation can’t be simplified to the elegant form
$$
\rho\left(\frac{\partial \vec u}{\partial t}+\vec u \cdot \nabla \vec u\right) = \vec s
$$
which is basically Newton’s second law.

That implies my version was wrong. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Especially in the last step: if you plug in $\vec{\varphi} = \rho \vec{u}$, then $\vec{\varphi}\otimes \vec{u} = \vec{u} \otimes \vec{\varphi}$, so there should be absolutely no difference between "your" version and the "Wiki" version.

Comment: Thank you@Willie Wong.That's exactly the answer I am looking for.  I should have noticed it earlier.